# Is it a good practice to convert WPF binding errors into Exceptions?

Tags: wpf, binding

I am designing a WPF application framework. One of the issues that I guess is good to consider, is errors in binding. These errors commonly raise because of misspelling or type conversions errors. WPF swallows these errors, and if these errors raise in production, would affect application behaviors badly.
There is a solution on github and the corresponding nuget package named [WpfBindingErrors](https://github.com/bblanchon/WpfBindingErrors). I tried that and it works nice.
But I'm not sure using this type of exception throwing for binding errors, is a good practice.